# Vimeo embeded video fails to play on Android?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, mobile, vimeo, fitvids

When I embed [100 Riffs (A Brief History of Rock N' Roll)](https://vimeo.com/43426940) in a [Twitter Bootstrap container](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem) with [FitVids.js](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js) for responsive resizing:

```
<div class="span12" id="video">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/43426940?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <p class="text-center">Isn't the placeholder video awesome?</p>
</div>
```

It functions fine on a desktop, but acts oddly on Android (CM 10.1 Nightly, Android 4.2.2) browsers:

- *Google Chrome* - Audio playback starts, but video playback does not
- *Mozilla Firefox* - Audio and video playback do not start

Yet, the player works fine on Vimeo's own mobile site. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, this is a [known issue](https://vimeo.com/forums/help/topic:101891) with the Vimeo player. I hope it gets fixed soon. For what it's worth, the stock/ASOP browser works fine.

**Update**: Vimeo has fixed this issue for most devices as of 2013-07-26.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a jQuery plugin that helps in some small way to mitigate this problem. Check it out.

https://github.com/JacobBennett/Android-Vimeo-Fix